# java .como puedo crear un metodo findAll() que tenga un paramentro

Tags: java, netbeans, crud

base de datos: en mi tabla Producto tengo
id - nombre- precio- descripción- id_category.

quiero crear que una lista que me traiga todos los productos de una determinada categoria.

Se me ocurre un findAll(id_categoria) pero no se como hacer el crud con esa idea.

Comment: Hola maqui, bienvenido, tu pregunta se parece mucho a "tengo este ejercicio, resuélvanlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, y obtengas una mejor respuesta.